# SELECT com contador sequencial não aceita LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

Porque ao fazer um `SELECT` que retorna um *sequence number* não funciona se tiver *LEFT JOIN*?

```
SELECT @ROW_NUMBER:=@ROW_NUMBER+1 AS ROW_NUMBER, 
       P.PEDIDOID
FROM PEDIDO AS P, 
     (SELECT @ROW_NUMBER:=0) AS T 
LEFT JOIN PEDIDOPRODUTO AS PP ON PP.PEDIDOID = P.PEDIDOID 
ORDER BY P.PEDIDOID DESC;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O motivo do erro está no [manual do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

> `INNER JOIN` and `,` (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is joined to each and every row in the second table).
>
> However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than of `INNER JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, and so on. If you mix comma joins with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur.
>
> (...)
>
> Now `JOIN` has higher precedence, so the expression is interpreted as `(t1, (t2 JOIN t3))`.

Ou seja, misturar um join implícito (com vírgula) com outros joins explícitos (`INNER`, `LEFT`, etc.) pode causar problemas pois a precedência da vírgula é menor que a dos joins explícitos.

No caso da sua query, os joins são interpretados como `(P, (T LEFT JOIN PP ON...))`, e isso não faz sentido, porque sua condição no `ON` não associa `T` a `PP`, e sim `P` a `PP`.

A solução é simples, basta usar um join explícito:

```
SELECT @ROW_NUMBER:=@ROW_NUMBER+1 AS ROW_NUMBER, 
       P.PEDIDOID
FROM PEDIDO AS P 
     INNER JOIN (SELECT @ROW_NUMBER:=0) AS T 
     LEFT JOIN PEDIDOPRODUTO AS PP ON PP.PEDIDOID = P.PEDIDOID 
ORDER BY P.PEDIDOID DESC;
```